# FCM message parsing to Java class using GSON

Tags: java, parsing, gson, deserialization

I am trying to parse the FCM message and build the java object

In the `FirebaseMessageService` the payload is parsed as follows

```
// Check if message contains a data payload.
if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.v(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    Map<String, String> params = remoteMessage.getData();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(params);
    Log.v(">>JSON_OBJECTTOSTRING ", object.toString())
```

The string retrieved is `{"message":"[{\"mName\":\"Milk\",\"mUnit\":\"1 Litre\"},{\"mName\":\"curd\",\"mUnit\":\"1 Litre\"}]"}`

The above string is parsed as below in another class

```
JsonObject jo = new JsonParser().parse(order).getAsJsonObject();
JsonArray jsonArray = jo.getAsJsonArray("message");
itemList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray, GroceryItem[].class);
```

Getting this error while retrieving as an array caused by:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonArray

could you help me?

Comment: Your json string is wrong. Json string should be like this `{\"message\":[{\"mName\":\"Milk\",\"mUnit\":\"1 Litre\"},{\"mName\":\"curd\",\"mUnit\":\"1 Litre\"}]}`. I parsed with this json string. It works.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON contains an inner JSON encoded as a string. If you take a closer look at the `message` property, you see that you should parse it again. Let's say:

```java
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
// get the outer root the way you already do
final JsonObject outerRoot = jsonParser.parse(JSON).getAsJsonObject();
// pick the inner JSON as a string
final String innerJson = outerRoot.get("message").getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
// and now you can parse it as a regular JSON
final JsonArray innerRoot = jsonParser.parse(innerJson).getAsJsonArray();
final GroceryItem[] groceryItems = gson.fromJson(innerRoot, GroceryItem[].class);
out.println(Arrays.toString(groceryItems));
```

And the output (assuming the `GroceryItem.toString()` method is defined somehow):

> [GroceryItem{mName='Milk', mUnit='1 Litre'}, GroceryItem{mName='curd', mUnit='1 Litre'}]